# How to print error message of why image failed to load?

Tags: gwt

Can we get any error information from an image load failure? I have the following:

```
Image image = new Image(imagePath);
image.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    Override
    public void onError(ErrorEvent event) {
        // what can we print here from 'event'?
    }
});
```

I have an image that fails to load once in awhile, and I just tried letting the event.toString() method print itself, but I just get something like:

```
println("Error!: " + event);
// "Error: An event type"
```

so I'm not sure why the image fails to load,

Thank you

Comment: Sorry. I don't think that you can do that. The ErrorEvent just contains 'error' as a static text.

Comment: why don't you check firebug? The console usually prints out this kind of errors or if you right click on the image, it may tell you if you are getting a resource not found or something

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I'm experiencing this at runtime on a mobile device. So I need to save some logs to a buffer and check them manually. So need a way to store what exactly happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't know what caused the error, but you can know what type of error caused it and it gives fairly a good idea on what might have gone wrong

```
 event.getAssociatedType();
```

OR

```
  event.getType();
```

Comment: That'll just return `error` right? In pure JS, the event in an `img.onerror` doesn't give a hint at what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Blast, that's the problem - would be super helpful to know the actual reason.